# Test if the nearest turtle is in-radius

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I try to ask to my turtles: if the nearest turtle is in radius lower to "distance-min" (a global), so get out!

But the following code doesn't work, and I really don't understand why.

```
to go
 ask boeufs [get-out]
 tick
end

to get-out
  let x min-one-of boeufs in-radius distance-min [distance myself]
  ifelse (x != nobody) [
    face x
    rt 180
    fd 1
    set color red
 ]     
 [
   wiggle
 ]
end
```

It seems like if: x equals to the turtle himself …
the condition is always true, even with only 1 turtle in the world, why? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`other`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other). All it does is take an agent set and remove the current agent from it. So your code becomes:

```
let x min-one-of other boeufs in-radius distance-min [distance myself]
```

`other boeufs` won't include the turtle itself, so it will never be reported by this.

Comment: So it's mean that when we use "min-one", we must always use "other".
Else the current agent his always returned, right?

Comment: It depends what you're doing for `min-one-of`. For instance, if you're doing `min-one-of [ energy ]` or something, you might want to know if the current agent has the lowest energy. But if your `min-one-of` references `myself`, chances are you want to use `other`.